# How to get a Mysql INSERT to signal pthread mutex

Tags: mysql, linux, unix, pthreads

I have a C code application running on Linux, which has a pthread blocked on a Mutex.
I wish to unblock this thread whenever an INSERT statement is made in a MysQL database. The thread will then go and read some data from the database.

So how do i get the Database to signal the mutex?

Thanks

Comment: Can you execute a process from an INSERT trigger?

Comment: Well yes if its safe to do, just wondering what is better what you suggested or just write into a one table row and poll it every second

Comment: Polling would probably be the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are vague on the specifics but assuming one (or more) threads are doing the insert and one (or more) threads need to be notified you probably want to use condition variables.  Basically the read threads call `pthread_cond_wait` and block until the insert threads successfully write the database and then call `pthread_cond_signal` to awaken the blocked read threads.

If some other program or mechanism is doing the inserts then this answer does not apply.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a trigger for that INSERT, which will give you a chance to run UDF (User-Defined Function). Function can run external code, which can wake up your program using `pthread_cond_signal`. I don't think it's recommended to write something like that, but it's possible.